# How to link a .lib in Visual Studio 2008 C++

Tags: visual-c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm finding it really difficult to properly link a .lib file to my C++ Win32 Console Application. Here's my problem.

Just as in this MSDN article, I have developed a MathFuncsLib.lib file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Then, in the MyExecRefsLib Win32 Console App, I want to link to the above file. So, inside MyExecRefsLib folder (same folder where .sln file resides) I created a directory called "LibraryFiles" and placed both MathFuncsLib.lib file AND MathFuncsLib.h file.

Then, in Properties->Linker->Input I added both "MathFuncsLib.lib" and "MathFuncsLib.h" (without full path) and then in Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories I added the path to my folder "LibraryFiles" which is what pretty much EVERY thread on the web about this problem tells me to do.

But now it gives me the following error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open the
>   include file. 'MathFuncsLib.h': No
>   such file or directory.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.
Note that my code is exactly the same as what's in the above given MSDN link.

Comment: Have you added the folder where that .h file resides into "additional include directories"?

Comment: @Sach (that setting can be found under properties->configuration properties->C/C++)

Comment: Additionally check spelling of the header file name. If you use a relative path name beware you start from the using project. If you use $(SolutionDir) in the path name, you will use a different (relative) path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys. I hadn't done that before so did what you said, but still it gives me the exact same error. (I ran Clean and then Rebuild.)

Comment: @harper
I don't think I understood you properly. Can you please elaborate again?

Comment: There are two possibilities when the compiler doesn't find a file: a) the name is wrong b) the compiler searches in the wrong place. To avoid (a) double check that you gave the right file name. To avoid (b) evaluate the effectiv search path. Usually you find something like "..\..\Some\Dir" in the "Additional Include Directories" field. You can open a command line and execute: "dir ..\..\Some\Dir\MathFuncsLib.h" to check if the file is in place. Further check if the setting is used for the source file in question and the active configuration (Debug/Release).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To link with a .lib file, you just need to:

- right clic on the project name, select Properties
- under Properties->configuration properties->C/C++->General item "other include directories" add the path to your .h file
- under Properties->Linker->Input add the path and name of your .lib file

And that's it.