# Making libraries and avoiding linker issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, header-files, libraries

I have about a dozen functions all related to the same purpose, and I am trying to create a library. A library that I can store away in a directory somewhere that I can then include as an include directory and just go about my business including said library in my projects that require its use.

---

**Side Note:**

First I'd like to say, I have given considerable time into finding an answer to this. I had thought I found a solution to it when I realized the linker would throw errors when I included the library in multiple source files. Now that I know that, I have again searched for an answer to my woes. I started looking at other libraries I know to do the same thing, or that I believe to. I looked at conio.h as I include it all the time for its kbhit() and getch() functions. Though I didn't understand most of what I had in it, I searched a few keywords and found that it may in fact be including the function definitions through a dll.

I've also done a handful of google searches.

---

To explain what I am doing a little bit. I have create 2 or 3 data structures that allow me to create chunks of data with headers that specify what the data is and how it is to be treated. Then a couple more for reading and writing those chunks to files.

To allow easy creation of these structures I have made stand-alone functions. To allow easy manipulation of these structures I have made even more stand-alone functions.

**I, simply put, need a way to include a library that somehow directly or indirectly defines all these functions and structures. How can I do so?**
*(without creating a myriad of inlines)*

Comment: What platform? linux or windows or...?

Comment: Are you trying to put everything in header files?

Comment: @doctorlove Windows, I've updated the tags to indicate my IDE. Up to this point, I had put everything in one header file. I see now that that will be difficult or more likely impossible. I am asking for assistance in determining an alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a `.lib` dependency in your code by using the `#pragma comment`

`#pragma comment (lib,"LibraryFileName.lib")`

You can read more about `#pragma comment` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

I normally like to make a a `Linker.h` file in my library soultion and include that file in every header found in my library. Here is an example of it.

```
#ifndef __GRAPHICCOMMUNICATOR_GUARD_linklib__
#define __GRAPHICCOMMUNICATOR_GUARD_linklib__

#if defined(_DEBUG)
    #pragma comment (lib,"GraphicCommunicator-mt-d.lib")
#elif !defined(_DEBUG)
    #pragma comment (lib,"GraphicCommunicator-mt.lib")
#else
    #error link: no suitable library
#endif

#endif // __GRAPHICCOMMUNICATOR_GUARD_linklib__
```

Comment: Just so I can make sure I understand your suggestion. Move my function definitions including class member function definitions to a cpp file. Compile that file into a lib file. then proceed with what you are saying?

Comment: You can then include your lib without using pragmas

Comment: @JoshC You declare your functions and classes in a header file, you declare the definition of the functions and class functions in a `.cpp` file. In your header file you put down the  `#pragma comment`. Then when you include the header file in a different project, it will link the `lib` automatically.

Comment: One thing you still have to worry about is the path of the library and includes. If the header and lib is not in the same folder of the project that uses the library you need to add these locations to the compiler to look for headers and libraries either globally or for the project using the library.

Comment: @Caesar Okay so, again to double check, the cpp file will automatically compile into a lib file and I can just replace the .cpp for .lib when I am referencing the lib file? If not I am horrendously lost in your explanation.

Comment: @JoshC Correct, you will need to build the project. This will compile all the `.cpp` files and give you a `.lib` file at the end. Now you have a library just like any other you get in C++ and you link it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Putting everything in one header is causing the problem. 

You can leave class member funnctions defined inline or other inline function in headers and include them more than once.

Otherwise you need to move implementations into cpp files and build a static (or dynamic) library. If you are learning, static may be easier. Make a new project and select "Static library" from the application settings.

To use the library you could use the `#pragma` answer from Caeser, or just add the `.lib` to the linker settings in the projects that wish to use it, along with `#including` the headers you need.

Comment: I was able to successfully create a static library back when I was first figuring out how to make a library out of this code. The problem I ran into was that it seemed that I needed to do more than just #include <file.h> or "file.h" to have it included. I had to actually add it to the project, or so the documentation I read indicated.

Comment: @JoshC - that's correct: the header only tells the compiler what functions are defined in the library. You **link** to the library to get those functions.

Comment: You can use pragma comment, or tell the linker settings about the library e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093325/how-to-link-a-lib-in-visual-studio-2008-c